# InfoSphere 11.3.1 Repository

Tags: sql-server, oracle, db2, datastage

Has anyone got any experience using a database othe than DB2 for an IBM InfoSphere 11.3.1 repository?

In 11.3.1, IBM added support for Oracle and SQL Server databases as the repository, and I'm curious to know what pros/cons other's may have run into using something other than DB2 since it's a new "feature".

Thanks!